# Design digital signal for 000001000101110 using all coding schemes

Tags: networking, computer-science, digital

How to create digital signals using these binary numbers?
Design digital signal for 000001000101110 using all coding schemes.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

[line code schemes for 000001000101110 ][1]
Answer

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdifT.jpg